# select index selenium 2 php

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I want to select an item from a drop down menu in selenium 2, in combination with phpunit. The class I use is PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase. I know in selenium 1 it's:

```
 $this->select("id=dt-general-input", "index=3");
```

But how des this convert to selenium 2? To select an element you do:

$this->select($this->byId("dt-general-input"));

But how do I select the 3rd index? This selection does not have (text) labeled options. So I can't use `$this->select($this->byId("dt-general-input"))->selectOptionByValue(3);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
$this->select($this->byId("dt-general-input"))->selectOptionByLabel('Label');
```

Or

```
$this->select($this->byId("dt-general-input"))->selectOptionByValue('the option value');
```

For

```
<option value="the option value">Label</option>
```

For the 3rd index you'd use 2 not 3 also by the way.

If your option values are all empty and you need the 3rd one in the list, then do

```
// Returns an array of elements 
$allOptions = $this->select($this->byId("dt-general-input"))->options();
$thirdOpton = $allOptions[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The method options() doesn't seem available for Selenium 2. But I can use selectOptionLabels() and selectOptionValues() instead.